# Mobile power bank shortlist

Tags: power-bank

It's hard to find a product selector with the option to select on detailed product spec.

I'm looking for a mobile phone power bank with roughly the following spec, although I could be flexible for "near misses":

- **Size** - Easily carried in jeans pocket with a phone or wallet, so probably slim (ish) - Id say 15mm ideally but I guess could consider up to 22mm (ish).
- **Capacity** - Ideally 15,000 mAh but would consider 10 - 30.
- **Power and fast charging stats** - Supports PD 3.0 and also any of QC 2.0/3.0/4.0 on outputs, able to charge 2 devices together, and some form of fast charge on input.  Ideally 25+W output on PD (though most seem to deliver up to 20W so flexible) and 12+W on QC. Kinda "not needing astronomical charge speeds but not sluggish either".
- **Connectors** - USB A and USB C outputs (at least one of each). Dont care input.
- **Availability** - Available in UK. (2nd hand used findable on EBay/Amazon is OK too)
- **Build quality** - Decent brand or reviews, likely decent quality.

Ive looked online but its hard to find that kind of info easily across current and recently discontinued models. Maybe someone knows more than I do what's around that might suit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I'd recommend this INIU 10000 mAh battery bank](https://www.amazon.co.uk/INIU-Charging-10500mAh-Portable-Flashlight/dp/B08JTQ66K7/)

[image]

- It's only 13 mm thick
- It's a little on the low side in terms of capacity (10000 mAh), but still within the range
- It supports USB-PD with 22.5 W of output, and QC 4.0
- It has dual Type-As and a Type-C
- It's available in the UK
- It's well built and from a reasonably well-known (if not super mainstream) brand. I personally use one of their higher capacity battery banks and it works great.
- It's inexpensive (under £20 after discounts)

I'd consider [this 18000 mAh battery bank as well](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BZRWPBC6), but it's from a less reputable brand and it isn't available in the UK.

Comment: Both look really good and appropriate (unknown 2nd brand notwithstanding).  How did you initially find these existed and such, though?  Pure chance or some actual method?

Comment: Basically just searching Amazon for power banks from brands I was aware of and seeing what they offered.

Comment: Well, i found the 2nd one (ubuy.com, cost a lot more as imported, but if its any good, i'll be happy. 18,000 is much more likely to be useful for long days away from power).  But both look really good.  I"ll let you know when it arrives, and thank you for both recs!

Comment: Bought the 18,000 mAh one, just arrived. Looks good. If it does what it says on the box, I'll be happy.  Might still get the other as a backup, or at least good to know it exists if the first one fails.  Pro tip - I've used a random phone plastic screen protector, as the front is black gloss and worth keeping the looks even though its not a touchscreen or anything.  Thank you!